# Accessing raw sockets on Raspberry pi using nodejs

Tags: linux, node.js, raspberry-pi, raw-sockets

i want to do a ip discovery on my local network . I have wrote a script using nodejs and debian linux and net-ping module off nodejs. Its working fine on my local machine.

But when it try and run it on my RaspberryPi device it gives operation not permitted error.

I even tried to give access to raw sockets to node via assigning capabilities setcap cap_net_raw=+e 'path to the node' but even that operation is not permitted.

Please someone suggest some solutions to let net-ping module access raw sockets .

Thanks

Comment: What distro are you using? Have you tried running the app as root?  `sudo app.js`?

Comment: i am running debian. Also running as a root exposes device to security issues so thats not an option. Also node command doesn't work with sudo.

Comment: Its a troubleshooting step at least.  Node absolutely can run with sudo.

Comment: Did you try JXcore's raspbian distro?

Comment: `cap_net_raw=e` doesn't mean anything. You might want to try `cap_net_raw=ep`.

Answer (score 0):

`net-ping` uses `node-raw-socket` which needs root access to create its raw sockets.

You will have to run your app with sudo:

```
sudo node app.js
```